# How to choose the branches of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ when doing a complex map

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, transformation, conformal-geometry

I am trying to find the correct branch of the complex cube root, and map the complex plane cut along the positive y axis onto the wedge $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(w)<\frac{\pi}{6}$. 
The function $w=\sqrt[3]{z}$ clearly does the job, however one has to choose the proper branch. I am doing this by guessing.

Choose

$$z=-i=e^{i\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k\right)},$$

which is in the original plane. Therefore, $k=-1$ does the job, since the argument of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ with the so chosen branch
$$
\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\pi\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6},
$$
is in the range $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(w)<\frac{\pi}{6}$. 
In general,

$$f(z)=e^{i\frac{1}{3}\left(Arg(z) - 2\pi\right)},$$

maps the the complex plane except the positive y axis to the angular segment $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(w)<\frac{\pi}{6}$. Here $Arg(z)$ is the principal value of the argument $Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$ or $Arg(z) \in [0,2\pi)$

In general, the solution goes as follows. The complex cube root has 3 values $\frac{\pi}{6}$ for $k=0$,$\frac{5\pi}{6}$ for $k=1$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ for $k=2$. That is, the cube root divides the complex plane into 3 equal angular segments.

Only the value $k=0$ touches the range of interest $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(w)<\frac{\pi}{6}$ , therefore, one has to go one revolution back and choose $k=-1$.

Why $k=-1$ is the part I do not understand.

Comment: We want to define the cube root as $z^{1/3} = |z|^{1/3} e^{i \arg(z)/3}$ (with positive $|z|^{1/3}$) and choose $\arg z$ in such a way that $\arg(z)/3 \in (-\pi/2, \pi/6)$, therefore we take $\arg z \in (-3 \pi/2, \pi/2)$. It doesn't matter how $\arg$ is defined on the positive $y$-axis.

Comment: Isn't $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$ the same as $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This is basically going a full circle starting at $\frac{\pi}{2}$? Could you give a more detailed answer.

Comment: It is not true that you can take $\arg z + 2 \pi k \in (-3 \pi/2, \pi/2)$. What is true is that you can take $\arg z + 6 \pi k \in (-3 \pi/2, \pi/2)$. But any $k$ gives the same $z^{1/3}$. Compute $(-1)^{1/3}$ with $z^{1/3}$ as defined in the first comment above.

Comment: The cube root has three values located at $\frac{\pi}{6},k=0$,$\frac{5\pi}{6},k=1$ and $\frac{3\pi}{6},k=2$
The magic value however is $k=-1$ or $\sqrt[3]{|z|}e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(Arg(z)-2\pi\right)}$ is the needed transformation . The question is, where $k=-1$ comes from

Comment: When you write $(\arg z - 2 \pi)/3$ (there should also be an $i$ factor), you have to specify how you define $\arg$. If you mean the principal value of the argument, the result is not an analytic function on $D = \mathbb C \setminus [0, i \infty)$. You're apparently considering the boundary of $D$, which is not a part of $D$. That is useful only if the mapping is continuous on the boundary. You cannot make the cube root continuous both from the left and from the right on $[0, i \infty)$.

Comment: I am confused, I learned that roots are defined as such: Fix the branch by defining the root for one value $a$, then compute any other value $z$ by using $|z|^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{\frac{i}{n}\left(\arg{a} + \Delta{\gamma_{az}}\arg{z} \right )}$ where $\Delta{\gamma}$ means, the change of the argument's value going from $a$ with $\arg{a}$ to $z$ along a smooth curve $\gamma$. The condition for the root to exists is $z\ne0$ and $\Delta_{\gamma}=n2\pi k$ for any closed loop $\gamma$, where $n$ is the type of root square $n=2$, cube $n=3$ etc. So can't I just take $a=-i$with $\arg{a}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that $\arg$ has infinitely many branches and thus $a <\arg(w)< b$ needs interpretation. You will certainly not like to have the branch cut of $\arg$ in the above region. Thus I suggest to consider an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $b - a \le 2\pi$ and define
$$G(a,b) = \{ re^{it} \mid r > 0, t \in (a,b) \}$$
instead of $G(a,b)  = \{ z \mid a < \arg(z) < b \}$. Obviously we have $G(a,b) = G(a +2k\pi,b+2k\pi)$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$. Note that
$$\mathbb C(c) = G(c,c+2\pi) = \mathbb C \mathbb \setminus L(c)$$
with $L(c) = \{ re^{ic} \mid r \ge 0 \}$ is a sliced plane with branch cut at an angle of $c$.

On each $\mathbb C(c)$ we have three distinct holomorphic branches $\beta^c_k$ of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ given by $\beta^c_k(re^{it}) =\sqrt[3]{r}e^{i(t + 2k\pi)/3}$ for $k = 0,1,2$ and $t \in (c,c+2\pi)$. Their range is $G^3_k(c) = G(c/3+k\pi/3,c/3+(k+1)\pi)$. Note that replacing $c$ by $c + 2\pi$ does not change the set $\mathbb C(c)$ and we get the **same** collection of three cubic root maps on $\mathbb C(c)$, but we have a cyclic index shift ($\beta^{c+2\pi}_k = \beta_{k+1}^c$, where we understand $2+1 = 0$).

Let us now consider the region $G(a, a + 2\pi/3)$. It is mapped by $z^3$ onto $\mathbb C(3a)$. Both sets only depend on  $a \mod 2\pi$. The branch $\beta_0^{3a}$ maps $\mathbb C(3a)$ onto $G(a, a + 2\pi/3)$.

In your case we have $a = -\pi/2$, thus the desired branch cut is at $-3\pi/2$ which is the same as at $\pi/2$. Thus the sliced plane is $\mathbb C \setminus$ positive $y$-axis. Note, however, that for the branch cut at $-3\pi/2$ we have to take
$$\sqrt[3]{z} = \beta_0^{-3\pi/2}(z), \text{ i.e. } \sqrt[3]{re^{it}} = \sqrt[3]{r}e^{it/3}  \text{ for } t \in (-3\pi/2,\pi/2)$$
and for the branch cut at $\pi/2$ we have to take
$$\sqrt[3]{z} = \beta_2^{\pi/2}(z), \text{ i.e. } \sqrt[3]{re^{it}} = \sqrt[3]{r}e^{i(t+4\pi)/3}  \text{ for } t \in (\pi/2,5\pi/2)$$
which is the same although  it looks different.

Comment: Is it fair to say, that to solve the problem, I have to make sure, that the multi- valued argument (by choosing proper $k$) $Arg(z)+2\pi k \in (-\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: You must first make a branch cut at some angle $c \in \mathbb R$, then you get infinitely many branches $\arg = \arg_k : \mathbb C(c) \to (c +2\pi k,c+2\pi(k+1))$. If you take the principal value (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)), then you take $c = - \pi$ and $\arg_0 : \mathbb C(-\pi) \to (-\pi,\pi)$. For no $k$ you then get values in $(-3\pi/2,\pi/2)$. In fact the branch cut for $\arg$ must be at $-3\pi/2$ or $\pi/2$.

Comment: I hope you are still around. Here is how I learned the branches of the $n$th root at school. Define the root for some point $a$ and then compute the value for any $z$ by using $|z|^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{\frac{i}{n}\left(\arg{a} + \Delta{\gamma_{az}}\arg{z} \right )}$ and computing how the argument of $z$ changes when going from $a$ to $z$ along the connecting curve $\gamma$. Using this definition, isn't $a=-i$ taking $\arg{a}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ the same to what you did?

Comment: @AlexanderCska What you try to do here is to associate to any $z$ a certain value of $\arg z$ by (1) choosing some $a$ and a value for $\arg z$  (2) considering a curve $\gamma_{az}$ from $a$ to $z$ (note that this curve must avoid $0$ because $\arg 0$ is not defined). You can do that, but now the value $\Delta \gamma_{az} \arg z$ depends on the **choices** of $a$, $\arg a$ and of $\gamma_{az}$. Ignoring the arbitrariness of $a$, the choice of $\arg a$ is relevant since you are dividing by $n$. The infinitely many possible choices of $\arg a$ yield $n$ distinct values of $\sqrt[n]{a}$.

Comment: But okay, let us fix some $\arg a$. Concerning the curve you may say "let's take the shortest curve" from $a$ to $z$, but that does not work if $z$ has the form $ta$ for $t < 0$: There is no shortest curve avoiding $0$. Okay, let us bend the line segment from $a$ to $z$ just a little to avoid $0$. But there are two choices to do so, and they yield different values for $\Delta \gamma_{az} \arg z$. You see: You end again with a branch cut at $L(-a)$. The whole procedure gives you $n$ distinct branches of $\sqrt[n]{z}$ on the sliced plane $\mathbb C(-a)$.

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't express myself precisely. The branch $\{ f(z)^{\frac{1}{n}} \}$ exists on a domain for which $f(z) \ne 0$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f′(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta=2\pi k$, for any closed smotth curve $\Gamma$. Due to this second property, the choice of the smooth connecting curve $\gamma_{az}$ is arbitrary and will yield the same result. This is how I learned to define complex roots.

Comment: The complex root is defined by $z^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(i\arg{a}+\int_{\gamma_{az}} \frac{f′(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta\right)}$, where fixing $\arg{a}$, actually fixes the branch.

Comment: @AlexanderCska In fact, *continuous* complex $n$-th root functions can be defined precisely on simply connected regions $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ which do not contain $0$. There are always $n$ distinct continuous $n$-th root functions (which are even holomorphic) on such $\Omega$ and you may define them as you have done via $\Delta \gamma_{az} \arg z$. The simplest way is when $\Omega$ is a sliced plane. But I am confused: What is the purpose of our discussion? I suggest you ask a new question if something needs clarification.

Comment: I was trying to merge what you told me with what I know. I think that you are write, I will prepare a more detailed question. I think that this will be also interesting for others, since it seems that this branch cut story is confusing for many.